# Qt5 crash on close

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qt5

My project crashes on close sometimes, but not reliably. When closed with the "Cancel" button, it crashes much less often than if closed with the escape key, which just further confuses me. I've got a simple find dialog (a small part of a larger project) as a form of a test case.

Attempts to debug with GDB result in it never crashing. Core dump is garbage (bad memory).

Included below is the source. I haven't been able to pinpoint what's actually going wrong; I've seen (with minor modifications) double free, free-ing NULL, free-ing a pointer that never existed, etc. and I'm beginning to wonder if it's partially Qt's fault.

Header:

```
#ifndef NIDE_FINDDIALOG_HPP
#define NIDE_FINDDIALOG_HPP

#include <QDialog>
#include <QString>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>

class FindDialog: public QDialog {
public:
    bool regex, caseSensitive, inSelection, wholeWord, forward, wrap;
    QString expr;

private:
    struct {
        QGridLayout *layout;
        QCheckBox *regex, *caseSense, *select, *whole, *forward, *wrap;
        QLineEdit *exprBox;
        QPushButton *cancel, *find;
    }ui;

    void onCancel();
    void onFind();

    void onRegex();
    void onCase();
    void onSelect();
    void onWhole();
    void onForward();
    void onWrap();

public:
    FindDialog(QWidget *parent);
    ~FindDialog();
};

#endif/*NIDE_FINDDIALOG_HPP*/
```

Source:

```
#include <NIDE/FindDialog.hpp>

FindDialog::FindDialog(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent),
    regex(false), caseSensitive(true), inSelection(false), wholeWord(true),
    forward(true), wrap(true), expr() {

    ui.layout       = new QGridLayout(this);    
    ui.regex        = new QCheckBox("Regex", this);
    ui.caseSense    = new QCheckBox("Match case", this);
    ui.select       = new QCheckBox("In Selection", this);
    ui.whole        = new QCheckBox("Whole Word", this);
    ui.forward      = new QCheckBox("Forward", this);
    ui.wrap         = new QCheckBox("Wrap around", this);
    ui.exprBox      = new QLineEdit(this);
    ui.cancel       = new QPushButton("Cancel", this);
    ui.find         = new QPushButton("Find", this);

    ui.regex->setChecked(regex);
    connect(ui.regex, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &FindDialog::onRegex);

    ui.caseSense->setChecked(caseSensitive);
    connect(ui.caseSense, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &FindDialog::onCase);

    ui.select->setChecked(inSelection);
    connect(ui.select, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &FindDialog::onSelect);

    ui.whole->setChecked(wholeWord);
    connect(ui.whole, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &FindDialog::onWhole);

    ui.forward->setChecked(forward);
    connect(ui.forward, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &FindDialog::onForward);

    ui.wrap->setChecked(wrap);
    connect(ui.wrap, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &FindDialog::onWrap);

    ui.exprBox->setPlaceholderText(tr("Find expr..."));
    connect(ui.exprBox, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &FindDialog::onFind);

    connect(ui.cancel, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &FindDialog::onCancel);

    ui.find->setDefault(true);
    connect(ui.find, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &FindDialog::onFind);


    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.regex, 0, 0);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.caseSense, 0, 1);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.select, 0, 2);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.whole, 1, 0);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.forward, 1, 1);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.wrap, 1, 2);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.exprBox, 2, 0, 1, 3);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.cancel, 3, 1);
    ui.layout->addWidget(ui.find, 3, 2);

    setLayout(ui.layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Find"));
}
FindDialog::~FindDialog() {
    delete ui.layout;
    delete ui.regex;
    delete ui.caseSense;
    delete ui.select;
    delete ui.whole;
    delete ui.forward;
    delete ui.wrap;
    delete ui.exprBox;
    delete ui.cancel;
    delete ui.find;
}

void FindDialog::onCancel() {
    done(QDialog::Rejected);
}
void FindDialog::onFind() {
    expr = ui.exprBox->text();
    done(QDialog::Accepted);
}

void FindDialog::onRegex() { regex = ui.regex->isChecked(); }
void FindDialog::onCase() { caseSensitive = ui.caseSense->isChecked(); }
void FindDialog::onSelect() { inSelection = ui.select->isChecked(); }
void FindDialog::onWhole() { wholeWord = ui.whole->isChecked(); }
void FindDialog::onForward() { forward = ui.forward->isChecked(); }
void FindDialog::onWrap() { wrap = ui.wrap->isChecked(); }
```

Main:

```
#include <NIDE/FindDialog.hpp>

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication *app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    FindDialog fd(NULL);

    app->setApplicationName("NIDE");

    fd.exec();
}
```

Comment: try doing the deletes on the destructor on the reverse order of creation

Comment: There shouldn't be any `delete` in your dtor. Indeed, you've set parents for your QObject (the `this` you've passed in each ctor), and they will handle their child's memory release.

Comment: Also, there's currently no need for a dynamically allocated `QApplication` in your main. Just create a statically allocated variable. And try to replace `fd.exec()` by `app->exec(); fd.show();` in the main as well. I can't say it will fix your problem 100%, but there's great chances it will.

Comment: Also, the usual way for Signal/Slot connection is to do `connect(&sender, SIGNAL(sender_signal(param_type)), &receiver, SLOT(receiver_slot(param_type)));`. May I suggest finding a really good tutorial for creating Qt applications, like this [**tutorial about a small text editor**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html), which will help you grasp the basics of Qt.

Comment: @JBL I only added the deletes after noticing it was crashing. Changing QApplication to be statically allocated and calling fd.show() then app.exec() completely solved the problem (or caused it to happen a lot less often; haven't seen it crash yet). I specifically am avoiding the traditional Qt signal/slot as I'm trying to avoid using Qt's "language extension" Q_OBJECT.

Comment: `Q_OBJECT` is not a language extension. It is a macro that saves you from typing a couple of lines of perfectly standard boilerplate C++ code. The implementation of one of the methods declared in this macro is generated by `moc`. Your avoidance of Qt features is puzzling. All of Qt's features are implemented in C++. The `moc` is a tool that saves you, again, from typing boilerplate code by hand. Your shunning of code generators makes you a *less* productive programmer/engineer. There's very little that could support your approach. Most arguments I've heard in this matter are very uninformed.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid using `Q_OBJECT`. It's completely standards, and lets you use Qt the right way (well, it doesn't save you from bad design though).

Answer (score 2):

In avoiding the use of `Q_OBJECT` macro you're relying on an implementation detail of Qt. It is undefined behavior to connect to methods that were *declared* in a class without `Q_OBJECT`. The fact that it works in a particular version of Qt is a happy coincidence.

Alas, your code does a lot of unnecessary things.

1. There's no need to keep Ui elements or `QApplication` instance on the heap.
2. There's no reason for all of the `onXxxx` methods since you won't be reading the state of the dialog while it is being shown through `exec()`. You only care about the state of the dialog after it has been accepted (or perhaps rejected).
3. You can leverage `QDialog::accept` and `QDialog::reject` slots.
4. To make the dialog look correctly on multiple platforms, you should use a `QDialogButtonBox` instead of discrete buttons.
5. Finally, using `QDialog::exec()` reenters the event loop and makes you think that your code is synchronous when it really isn't. It's a source of hard to find bugs. You should simply `show()` the dialog and react to the `accepted` signal that it emits when the Find button is clicked.

The code below attempts at being a reasonably correct solution. It works in both Qt 4 and Qt 5.

```
// Interface
#include <QDialog>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>

#if QT_VERSION<QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#define Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
#endif

class FindDialog: public QDialog {
   struct Ui {
      QGridLayout layout;
      QCheckBox regex, caseSense, select, whole, forward, wrap;
      QLineEdit exprBox;
      QDialogButtonBox buttonBox;
      Ui(QWidget * widget);
   } m_ui;
   void get();
public:
   bool regex, caseSensitive, inSelection, wholeWord, forward, wrap;
   QString expr;

   FindDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~FindDialog();
   void set();
   void done(int r) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

// Implementation
FindDialog::Ui::Ui(QWidget * widget) :
   layout(widget),
   regex(tr("Regex")),
   caseSense(tr("Match case")),
   select(tr("In Selection")),
   whole(tr("Whole Word")),
   forward(tr("Forward")),
   wrap(tr("Wrap around")),
   buttonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel)
{
   layout.addWidget(&regex, 0, 0);
   layout.addWidget(&caseSense, 0, 1);
   layout.addWidget(&select, 0, 2);
   layout.addWidget(&whole, 1, 0);
   layout.addWidget(&forward, 1, 1);
   layout.addWidget(&wrap, 1, 2);
   layout.addWidget(&exprBox, 2, 0, 1, 3);
   layout.addWidget(&buttonBox, 3, 0, 1, 3);
   exprBox.setPlaceholderText(tr("Find expr..."));
   buttonBox.addButton(tr("Find"), QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole);
}

FindDialog::FindDialog(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent), m_ui(this),
   regex(false), caseSensitive(true), inSelection(false), wholeWord(true),
   forward(true), wrap(true)
{
   set();
   connect(&m_ui.buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), SLOT(reject()));
   connect(&m_ui.buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), SLOT(accept()));
   setWindowTitle("Find");
}

FindDialog::~FindDialog() {}

void FindDialog::done(int result)
{
   get();
   QDialog::done(result);
}

void FindDialog::get()
{
   regex = m_ui.regex.isChecked();
   caseSensitive = m_ui.caseSense.isChecked();
   inSelection = m_ui.select.isChecked();
   wholeWord = m_ui.whole.isChecked();
   forward = m_ui.forward.isChecked();
   wrap = m_ui.wrap.isChecked();
   expr = m_ui.exprBox.text();
}

void FindDialog::set()
{
   m_ui.regex.setChecked(regex);
   m_ui.caseSense.setChecked(caseSensitive);
   m_ui.select.setChecked(inSelection);
   m_ui.whole.setChecked(wholeWord);
   m_ui.forward.setChecked(forward);
   m_ui.wrap.setChecked(wrap);
}

// Main
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   app.setApplicationName("NIDE");
   FindDialog fd;
   fd.show();
#if QT_VERSION>=QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
   // This can't be done in Qt4 without using moc
   QObject::connect(&fd, &QDialog::accepted, [&fd]{
      QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Find",
         QString("The user wants to find \"%1\"").arg(fd.expr));
   });
#endif
   return app.exec();
}
```